# How to quantify the "resolution" of "Fractional factorial design"?

Tags: experiment-design, fractional-factorial

The Design Expert software gives me the picture of resolution for the fractional factorial design, in which Resolution III, IV and V are most critical.

But can I ask, how can I determine the resolution by myself, based on the number of factors?

[image]